# html code not running on notepad++

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried running my HTML code via notepad++ on chrome but does not seem to work. This code is basically an animation of circles revolving around a bigger circle. For some odd reason, my code does not run the animation. Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">

        div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  position: fixed;
}

#center {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}

#sat0,
#sat1,
#sat2,
#sat3,
#sat4 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}


        </style>
</head>
    <body>
    <div id="center"></div>
<div id="sat0"></div>
<div id="sat1"></div>
<div id="sat2"></div>
<div id="sat3"></div>
<div id="sat4"></div>


        <script language="JavaScript"  type="text/javascript">


            var pos = $('#center').position(),
  radiusSat = $('#sat1').width() * 0.5,
  radius = $('#center').width() * 0.5,
  cx = pos.left + radius,
  cy = pos.top + radius,
  x, y, angle = 0,
  angles = [],
  spc = 360 / 5,
  deg2rad = Math.PI / 180,
  i = 0;

for (; i < 5; i++) {
  angles.push(angle);
  angle += spc;
}

/// space out radius
radius += (radiusSat + 10);

loop();

function loop() {

  for (var i = 0; i < angles.length; i++) {

    angle = angles[i];

    x = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle * deg2rad);
    y = cy + radius * Math.sin(angle * deg2rad);

    $('#sat' + i).css({
      left: x - radiusSat,
      top: y - radiusSat
    });

    angles[i] = angles[i] + 1;
    if (angles[i] > 360) angles[i] = 0;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}




        </script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

I cannot find any mistakes that I might have made. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you're... running code on notepad++? what? did you mean you're editing the code with notepad++?

Comment: Learn to use the developer tools in your browser. The problem would be a lot more obvious is you looked at the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. You are trying to use jQuery ($) without including jQuery library.
Please insert this

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
```

Before this:

```
<script language="JavaScript"  type="text/javascript">
```

Or better inside `<head></head>` tags

Comment: thank you. you are amazing!!!!

Comment: Glad to help. When coding in JS, use Chrome console. Press F12 and select console tab. There you will see useful things.

Comment: Any reason for downvote ?

Comment: I upvoted your answer

Comment: @gordonsung not you. Someone down-voted both me and other answer. Apparently the reason is unknown.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't add `jQuery` reference in your file.

Add this in your `<head>` tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you. you are amazing!!

Comment: @gordonsung - glad to help. look at the developer tools and console in particular in the future.. it will show any javascript errors

Comment: @downvoter - any reason?

Comment: I upvoted your answer

Comment: @gordonsung - haha.. I know you didn't. I was mereley pointing to someone who downvoted both the answers in this post.